# Trying to fill NaNs with fillna() and groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nan

So I basically have an Airbnb data set with a few columns. Several of them correspond to ratings of different parameters (cleanliness, location,etc). For those columns I have a bunch of NaNs that I want to fill.

As some of those NaNs correspond to listings from the same owner, I wanted to fill some of the NaNs with the corresponding hosts' rating average for each of those columns.

For example, let's say that for host X, the average value for review_scores_location is 7. What I want to do is, in the review_scores_location column, fill all the NaN values, that correspond to the host X, with 7.

I've tried the following code:

```
cols=['reviews_per_month','review_scores_rating','review_scores_accuracy','review_scores_cleanliness','review_scores_checkin','review_scores_communication','review_scores_location','review_scores_value']

for i in cols:
  airbnb[i]=airbnb[i].fillna(airbnb.groupby('host_id')[i].mean())
```

Although it does run and it doesn't return any error, it does not fill the NaN values, since when I check if there are still any NaNs, the amount hasn't changed.

What am I doing?

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that when using the series `airbnb.groupby('host_id')[i].mean()` in the `fillna`, the function tries to align index and as the index of `airbnb.groupby('host_id')[i].mean()` are actually the values of the column `host_id` and not the original index values of `airbnb`, the `fillna` does not work as you expect. Several options are possible to do the job, one way is to use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) after the `groupby` that will align the `mean` value per group to the original index values and then the `fillna` would work as expected, such as:

```
for i in cols:
    airbnb[i]=airbnb[i].fillna(airbnb.groupby('host_id')[i].transform('mean'))
```

And even, you can use this method without a loop such as:

```
airbnb = airbnb.fillna(airbnb.groupby('host_id')[cols].transform('mean'))
```

with an example:

```
airbnb = pd.DataFrame({'host_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 
                       'reviews_per_month':[4,5,np.nan,9,3,5],
                       'review_scores_rating':[3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,7,8]})
print (airbnb)
   host_id  review_scores_rating  reviews_per_month
0        1                   3.0                4.0
1        1                   NaN                5.0
2        1                   NaN                NaN
3        2                   NaN                9.0
4        2                   7.0                3.0
5        2                   8.0                5.0
```

and you get:

```
cols=['reviews_per_month','review_scores_rating'] # would work with all your columns
print (airbnb.fillna(airbnb.groupby('host_id')[cols].transform('mean')))
   host_id  review_scores_rating  reviews_per_month
0        1                   3.0                4.0
1        1                   3.0                5.0
2        1                   3.0                4.5
3        2                   7.5                9.0
4        2                   7.0                3.0
5        2                   8.0                5.0
```

Comment: Totally works! Thank you so much for the explanation!